# How do you implement Django namespaces

Tags: django, namespaces

I have started my journey with Django and I am thoroughly loving it. I do have a question about namespaces which I hope someone will be able to help me with and explain why it works like that.

I understand namespaces are used to make sure that if you have two pages with the same name that the url and reverse function points to the right page. I have been trying to implement namespaces in a test app I am writing but have not been able to do it.

Here is what I have so far (This is without namespaces as I haven't been able to get it to work.

Extract from app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [

 path('', views.index, name = "index"),
]
```

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
import gallery



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('index/', include('gallery.urls')),
]
```

And lastly, this is my view.py file in my app folder

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,"gallery/index.html")
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

URL namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even if different applications use the same URL names. It’s a good practice for third-party apps to always use namespaced URLs (as we did in the tutorial). Similarly, it also allows you to reverse URLs if multiple instances of an application are deployed. In other words, since multiple instances of a single application will share named URLs, namespaces provide a way to tell these named URLs apart. See  [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

In your case:

**project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
import gallery



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='your-namespace')),
    path('index/', include('gallery.urls',namespace='your-namespace')),
]
```

**Extract from app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [

 path('', views.index, name = "index"),
]
```

in the template:

```
{% url 'app:index' %}
```